# android random exception when resuming Unable to start activity ComponentInfo android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

I have quite strange exception which appears when my app is resumed (after I switch to other apps and then return to mine) although it's not thrown always but only from time to time.

The part where exception is quite simple. I use ViewPager (v4) and have two dialog classes, first child DialogHelp:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState); [line 50]
```

second the parent PMDialogFragment (extends DialogFragment):

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
app = (PMApplication) getActivity().getApplication();

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container); [line 50]
```

and below logcat:

```
    12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pitersoft.pitermemoflashcards/pitermemo.android.gui.activities.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1964)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1989)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1155)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4482)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1041)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2191)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:880)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at pitermemo.android.gui.dialogs.PMDialogFragment.onCreateView(PMDialogFragment.java:50)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at pitermemo.android.gui.dialogs.DialogHelp.onCreateView(DialogHelp.java:50)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4475)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1937)
12-02 00:48:04.532: E/AndroidRuntime(22292):    ... 11 more
```

I really don't know what causes that and how to solve this. If it was repeated always, it would be much easier.

I'm thinking perhaps it's somehow related with WebView component which likes to make problems. Another suspicious thing is in onResume of main app I run sometimes AsyncTask. But the log doesn't suggest this.

Do you have any suggestions what can cause this? Thanks in advance. (android min sdk 11, run on device with android 4.0.4).

Comment: what is line 50 of PMDialogFragment?

Comment: As it's marked above: View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container); [line 50]

Comment: Have You checked the app for memory leaks?